# matplotlib colormap with more than 256 steps?

Tags: matplotlib

I just became curious.
Are matplotlib colormaps always 256-step?

I believe there is no such thing in the registered colormap list. But is there any hope I can make a custom colormap of more steps? for example, a 512-step colormap?

Comment: Sure. See e.g. [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25679992/788700).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mapping range of integer values to colors in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25674789/mapping-range-of-integer-values-to-colors-in-python)