# What is the limitation for coloring cells a matrix with seaborn?

Tags: python-3.x, seaborn

I created a random matrix with n rows and m columns with numpy:

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sb

matrix= np.random.rand(n, m)
```

and I tried to paint it with seaborn heatmap:

```
sb.heatmap(data)
```

I don't know the value of n and m, and I want to paint the matrix so that each cell has a different color, there are no two cells with the same color. I have to find how many cells can be painted? I mean, how can I know how many of these cells can be painted with different colors when the value of n and m is not known? n and m can be very large.

Comment: I think matplotlib's colormaps are restricted to 256 different colors. So `data=np.arange(256).reshape(16,-1)` would be a maximising example.  With pure random data, many cells will get the same color (and many colors staying unused).

Comment: @JohanC can you give me some links about this subject or link to articles for this subject, I can not find a related topic to show whether seaborn has restrictions on painting or not, I am so confused.

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25674789/mapping-range-of-integer-values-to-colors-in-python/25679992#25679992), more colors are possible.  But note that when saving to most file formats (e.g. [PNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics)) or displaying on a screen, colors will be converted to 24 or 32 bit,  with maximum 256 values for each of the red, green and blue component. 256 colors is a limitation in matplotlib's standard color maps.  Note that all this is completely independent of seaborn. Matplotlib's backend controls the limitations.